# Vim search in all project files

Tags: vim

can somebody help me how to search for text in all project files (windows)

I've tried:

```
vimgrep /user/ **.*
```

It found only 1 match, but I'm sure i have 2 files with "user" text in it.

If I can do it without plugin or other program that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: `vimgrep /user/ **/.*` might help, separates the dir glob from the filename glob.

Answer (score 1):

The `**` is a special built-in glob operator. As documented under [`:help starstar`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#starstar), it can only be used in certain locations:

> ```
> - '**' can only be at the end of the path or be followed by a path
>   separator or by a number and a path separator.
> ```

So, you need to put a path separator (`/`) in between; without that, Vim treats every single `*` as a glob operator, and just searches the current directory:

```
:vimgrep /user/ **/.*
```